# How to apply Jekyll theme on Github Pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I made a repository on Github named username.github.io

Then I uploaded a Jekyll theme that I have downloaded.  After that I edited URL on config.yml file.

I expected a website with a new theme but it does not show up.

My question is do I must go through Ruby and Bundler process using CMD ? 
Is there any way I could just simply download theme, upload it on my repository, and make MD file there?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I could just simply download theme, upload it on my repository, and make MD file there?

A theme contains layouts, assets and collection/.md files. They can be placed in their [respective directories](https://jekyllrb.com). So the answer is 'yes'.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Default themes provided in the settings do not have any directories needed. But when I use themes provided by other users, it seems like it require many folders and files.